# Count values of the first object property that are greater than N and create another object

Tags: javascript

I have an arrays of key-value pairs like this:

```
let array = [{val:21, let:'a'}, {val:18, let:'b'}, {val:35, let:'c'}, {val:25, let:'d'}];
```

I want to iterate through val values and dynamically create another object where the key will be the number from 10 to 59 with the step 10 and the value - number of values in array that are greater than this number.

So that the result should look like this:

```
10:4, 20:3, 30:1 ...
```

I tried to make a loop, but as I do not know js it seems I did a mistake.

```
let dict = new Object();

//let keys = array.map(o => Object.values(o)[0]); 

for (i=10; i<=90; i+=10){
     dict.key= i;
    var count = 0;
    for (value in array){
      if (array.Object.values(o)[0] >= i) {
        dict.value[i] = count++;
    }
}
    };
```

What should I change in my loop?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how this result comes 10:4, 20:3, 30:1

Comment: what the `;` doing at the end there?

Comment: what's `array.Object.values(o)[0]`?

Comment: I think @Ison wants to sum up how many inner object values are greater than a specific number: `10:4` means all four example values (21, 18, 35 and 25) are greater than 10; `20:3` means only 3 "val" entries (21, 35 and 25) are greater than 20 and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to let each `i` be a key in your `dict` object, which you can then reference to get the current number of occurrences currently seen. Also, when looping over an array, you should use `for...of` instead of `for...in` as `for...in` can loop over unwanted properties. See example below:

```js
const dict = {};
const array = [{val:21, let:'a'}, {val:18, let:'b'}, {val:35, let:'c'}, {val:25, let:'d'}];

for (let i = 10; i <= 59; i += 10) {
  dict[i] = 0;
  for (obj of array) {
    if (obj.val >= i) {
      dict[i]++;
    }
  }
};

console.log(dict);
```

Alternatively, you could take an approach which incorporates logic over arrays by using methods such as `.map()`, `.filter()` and `.reduce()` like so:

```js
const count_occurances = (arr, s, e, step) =>
  Array(Math.ceil((e - s) / step)).fill().map((p => _ => p += step)(s - step))
    .reduce((a, i) => (a[i] = arr.filter(({val}) => val >= i).length, a), {});


const array = [{val:21, let:'a'}, {val:18, let:'b'}, {val:35, let:'c'}, {val:25, let:'d'}];
console.log(count_occurances(array, 10, 59, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a loop and check the value.

```js
let array = [{val:21, let:'a'}, {val:18, let:'b'}, {val:35, let:'c'}, {val:25, let:'d'}],
    max = 50,
    count = array.reduce((r, { val }) => {
        var k = max;
        do {
            r[k] = (r[k] || 0) + (val > k);
        } while (k -= 10)
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(count);
```

A different approach by using the value directly.

```js
let array = [{val:21, let:'a'}, {val:18, let:'b'}, {val:35, let:'c'}, {val:25, let:'d'}],
    count = array.reduce((r, { val }) => {
        val = Math.floor(val / 10);
        do {
            r[val * 10] = (r[val * 10] || 0) + 1;
        } while (--val)
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), then check if each `item.val` is greater than than each map key

```js
let array = [{val:21, let:'a'}, {val:18, let:'b'}, {val:35, let:'c'}, {val:25, let:'d'}];


let result = new Map([[10, 0],[20, 0],[30, 0],[40, 0],[50, 0]]);

array.forEach(item => 
              {
                  result.forEach((value, key) =>
                              {
                                  if(item.val > key)
                                  {
                                      result.set(key, value+1);
                                  }
                              });
              });
                        
result.forEach((value, key)=>{console.log(`${key}:${value}`)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You were looping incorrectly. Try this.

```
let array = [{val:21, let:'a'}, {val:18, let:'b'}, {val:35, let:'c'}, {val:25, let:'d'}];
let dict = {};

for (let i = 10; i <= 90; i += 10) {
  dict[i] = 0;
  for (let k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    if ( array[k].val >= i) {
      dict[i]++;
    }
  }
};

console.log(dict);
```